# Remove second character in a string in DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column of names that include the middle initial. I need to remove the middle initial which is the second character in the string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'beta': ['JRLeparoux', 'BJHernandez,Jr.','SXBridgmohan'],})
```

Here is what I tried:

```
def fixbadname(word):
    filelist2= [] 
    filelist = []
    for elem in word:
        filelist.append(elem)
         for file in filelist:
            file = file.replace(file[1],"") 
            filelist2.append(file)

    return filelist2

df['beta'].apply(fixbadname)
```

This is the desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'beta': ['JLeparoux', 'BHernandez,Jr.','SBridgmohan'],})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.beta = df.beta.str[0:1] + df.beta.str[2:];`
That should work.
If you want some explanations; ask me.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in several different ways with the vectorised string methods.

One way would be to use `slice_replace`:

```
>>> df['beta'] = df['beta'].str.slice_replace(1, 2)
>>> df
  alpha            beta
0     1       JLeparoux
1     2  BHernandez,Jr.
2     3     SBridgmohan
```

This method chooses a slice of the string (here it's the slice `[1:2]`) and replaces it with a replacement string. If no replacement string is given as the third argument, the empty string `''` will be used.